# How to solve Dataset Error - DataSet doesn't support 'union' or 'list' as simpleType

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dataset, readxml

I need to convert some XML (it seem that the XML complitated structure) to C# dataset.

So at first I tried to create dataset structure from XSD with:

```
ds.ReadXml(@"D:\data_RUIAN\ruian\xsd\vymenny_format\VymennyFormatTypy.xsd", XmlReadMode.Auto);
```

But it´s trowing an arror: **DataSet doesn't support 'union' or 'list' as simpleType**

Next I try to avoid loading XSD, so I load the source XML file directly:

```
ds.ReadXml(@"D:\data_RUIAN\data\20130831_OB_577405_UKSH.xml", XmlReadMode.Auto);
```

But it´s trowing anothe error - **Nested table 'Point' which inherits its namespace cannot have multiple parent tables in different namespaces.**

Please can you help me solve this?
Tahnks a lot!

Btw: XML is valid, I tried XSD2DB, xsd.exe., svcutil too but with no progress

Answer (score 2):

Conversion to a data set is riddled with limitations. Some may be bypassed through refactoring of the XSD (e.g. by removing the union and simple types). [This section on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b4194wc.aspx) provides general info re: the inference process.

The answer depends also on how you plan on filling in the data set, and whether you also want to generate XML from the data set that should match some spec. For example, you can choose to ignore the XML namespaces when you infer the set (see [DataSet.InferXmlSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135411.aspx)), which may solve the nested table error.